# Wanted to know the correct way of using sed command by inserting text from one file to another?

Tags: sed, text

Due to some problems in this site when it comes to displaying. I am using '{' instead of '<'.

Here is my sed command:

```
sed 's/{head/*backbutton_and_scroller_script.txt*{head/' report.usc20.txt
```

I want to insert text information from inside 'backbutton_and_scroller_script.txt' into 'report.usc20.txt' file in front of the head tag. How can I properly point towards the backbutton_and_scroller_script.txt file in my sed command? My current code is displaying the file name *backbutton_and_scroller_script.txt* infront of the head tag inside report.usc20.txt rather than the text that is inside the backbutton_and_scroller_script.txt.

Comment: I edited one line just to get you started

Comment: Rui F Ribeiro It is not a duplicate it is a different topic. Instead of trolling on my pages, either you can help me out, or troll another page.

Comment: No one properly answered my the previous questions. That is why I wanted to post another topic. If you don't like it, find something more creative to do than trolling on my pages.

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281492/how-to-add-a-new-text-line-at-the-first-line-of-a-file and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284170/replace-a-long-string-with-the-sed-command-argument-list-too-long-error

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem to have some misunderstandings of how `sed` works. `sed` doesn't have a "redirect file into this part of the pattern" operator. If you could redirect anything in there you would then have to escape any special characters in the input text to avoid messing up the pattern (this includes characters like dot and slash, so not exactly uncommon ones). And to *modify* a file you need to use the `-i` option to `sed`.

This may not be what you want to hear, but `sed` is the wrong tool for this job. The best thing you can do is get a tool or library which *understands* this type of markup (such as XSLT or a Python/Java/Ruby library).

If you are using some completely custom language you can use a horrible hack to read the file up to the first occurrence of `{head`:

```
file="$(<report.usc20.txt)"
start="${file%%\{head*}"
```

, get the corresponding rest of the file:

```
end="${file#*\{head}"
```

and finally chuck all the pieces together:

```
printf '%s%s{head%s' "$start" "$(<backbutton_and_scroller_script.txt)" "$end" > report.usc20.txt
```

This is untested and horrible and I recommend using a proper programming language instead.

Comment: Hey. I found the right way to do it. But thanks anyways for the help.